# How to Install new version Android App and make sure they override the previous one

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

This is Not any bug but when i rerun different builds on several test machines emulators, and they just create new ones without asking whether to uninstall the previous version of the app. I changed the package name each time when building, and the machine takes it as another app with having the same application name

Comment: Don't change the package name.

Comment: System doesn't care what is the name of the app. It looks for the package name. That is the identifier.

Comment: but i do need to change something? sorry i tested whole day doing the .apk thing yesterday, run out of brain juice. If i don't change anything the new .apk can't be installed

Comment: @james teo :change the versionCode  in gradle. let me knw what is you get

Comment: @JamesTeo : didi u get the answer. ?

Comment: thanks, yup working now. I just happen to see many patches that comes with build##, and thought the proper method is to change the package name with builds##

Comment: @JamesTeo : thanks, if the answer is helpful for u plz accept it and upvote it , it will be helpful for others also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to update the version code for each update.

android:versionCode — An integer value that represents the version of the application code, relative to other versions.

The value is an integer so that other applica
tions can programmatically evaluate it, for example to check an upgrade or downgrade relationship. You can set the value to any integer you want, however you should make sure that each successive release of your application uses a greater value. The system does not enforce this behavior, but increasing the value with successive releases is normative